# How to set html tags inside the input text box by Jquery in IE 8?

Tags: jquery

Jquery + html

```
html = "<i class='icon-rupee'></i>"
$("#amount").val(html + 500 + html + 300); //Wrong (because string is coming, output should show html_safe)
```

output is coming:
input field with value : `<i class='icon-rupee'></i>500<i class='icon-rupee'></i>300`

output wanted:
input field with value : ₹500 ₹300

How to set the html code inside input text field.
Any solution/help

Comment: You can simply use the icon outside the input box. As such you will not perform any operation on the icon. As it is only for display purpose, use it outside the text field.

Comment: @karan3112 Actually i need to show two icons inside the input box... not only one...

Comment: @haim770 how can i use .html() on input text field.

Comment: @user3676578, I was wrong, didn't notice it's an `input`.

Comment: How about using it as a symbol - `₹` ?

Comment: @Vucko this ₹ symbol won't work in IE8.it will come as box.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to manipulate HTML elements inside inline elements as input.

One possible way is to work with contenteditable blocks :
Create a fake input, display what ever you want in it, bind some keyboards events on it and change your real input with the values of your fake input...

I think it is definitely not a good practice with HTML5, but it seems to work :

http://jsfiddle.net/6eHvB/2/

HTML

```
<input type='text' readonly name='amount' id='amount' value='500 300' />
<div id='fake-amount' contenteditable></div>
```

JS

```
var html = " <i class='fa fa-rupee'></i> ";
$("#fake-amount").html(html + 500 + html + 300).focus().on('keyup', function (event) {
    $('#amount').val($(this).text());
});
```

Compatibility IE6+ :
http://caniuse.com/contenteditable